# TeX Live 2013 on Red Hat 6.4

Tags: installing, texlive, linux

As many of you know, Red Hat 6.4 comes with obsolete version of TeX Live from 2007. Unfortunately, TeX Live is dependency for many important packages we use in the Lab most notably `R-3.0.2`. Could anybody share the wisdom or point me to a document describing the installation of TeX Live 2013 on the Red Hat in the sandbox so that it doesn't conflict with the default TeX installation?

I would be happy to test somebody's RPM only if they behave like `Python 2.7.5` (unfortunately actual version is `2.7.3`) RPMs vs obsolete system Python. Note also that changing the operating system is not an option as I am not doing this for fun or hobby.

Comment: ...and Red Hat attacks again.

Comment: @juliohm Please tell me what else I can use for scientific computing? BSDs suggestions are in particularly welcome. That was not a sarcasm. I am an OpenBSD guy as most people here know familiar with other BSD flavors and full aware of strengths and limitations. I am all ears.

Comment: What is wrong with installing it by hand, using the TUG installer and manually edit the system PATH, that's what we did with our systems.

Comment: @daleif Nothing. I just would like to hear what other people do before trying to come up with something on my own.

Comment: I think a lot of people have given up with regards to LaTeX from Linux dists, they usually have different agendas.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac, a bit off-topic, I just feel sorry for Red Hat users in general, not because of this particular issue you've raised, but for many other obsolete software that comes with this distribution. If you're allowed to use an up-to-date Linux operating system, do so. Life is much easier, particularly for developers.

Comment: @juliohm I am allowed to use whatever I want as long as people can do their jobs. As I said earlier I am a BSD guy so I have no horse in that race. I am open for any suggestions except Ubuntu. We tested that. Please tell me what you guys use at work for scientific computing. I am taking here some serious scientific computing not kids playing.

Comment: Pardon my question, are we talking about RHEL or the old pre-Fedora RH?

Comment: @Paulo Cereda I use the latest RHEL

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: Since you are talking about RHEL: Pester RH support to support updated packages - you paid for it. Or use a free clone (like CentOS or Scientific). And create TL2013 packages for it - the ones for Fedora or OpenSUSE would be a good starting point.

Comment: @daleif: TL support for OpenSUSE and Debian is pretty good.

Comment: @Martin Schröder We are using PUIAS and ROCKS in the Lab which are  free derivatives of RedHat just like Scientific Linux or CentOS.

Comment: @Martin Schröder I think I said that changing the OS to accommodate TeXLive is not an option.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: Install vanilla TL2013 or build your own packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually got a great answer to this question on the [Springdale Linux formerly known as PUIAS Linux 
mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/springdale-users/NQLcRADEjAc). I am posting it here so that community can benefit from the answer.

> Hi Predrag,
>
> What we have done in our environment is download and install the
>   latest texlive from TUG onto an NFS share, then we use environment
>   modules to handle the user's environment variables
>   (PATH,MANPATH,INFOPATH).
>
> - Download TeX Live from http://www.tug.org/texlive/
> - Run the install-tl script
> - Install the environment-modules package from the computational repository
> - In the modulesfiles directory, create a texlive directory, then create a file called 2013
> - The 2013 file should look something like:

```
#%Module1.0#######################################################################
#
#
module-whatis   "Loads settings for the TeXLive 2013"
prepend-path    PATH            /usr/local/tex/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux
prepend-path    MANPATH         /usr/local/tex/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/man
prepend-path    INFOPATH        /usr/local/tex/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/info
```

> Your path will depend on where you install your distribution.
>
> - Now you can use "module load texlive" to load the latest texlive
> - You can have multiple files in the texlive directory (e.g. 2011, 2012, etc.), which would allow you to load different distributions if
>     you like, "module load texlive/2012"
>
> Hope that helps.
>
> Thanks, 
>   Theresa

Comment: I tried to format the code in a more sensible way, but the question marks seem wrong